# Dynamically change only one element in tooltip title using tooltipster

Tags: jquery, tooltip, tooltipster

I have a set of options in a [tooltipster](http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/) title attribute, like follow:

```
<i class="icon-cog settings" title="
                   <div class='div1' onclick='follow(1,2)'>Content 1</div>
                   <div class='div2' ...>Content 2</div>
                   <div class='div3' ...>Content 3</div>
                                                   ">
</i>
```

When the div1 is clicked, the content is dinamically updated by a ajax result based on the following function:

```
function follow(f1,f2) {
$.get('/exe/add_followers.php?f1=' + f1 + '&f2=' + f2, function (result) {
    $('.div'+f2).html('content 1 is updated to' + result.newcontent);
    }, 'json');
}
```

The problem is that when the tooltip is closed and the page has not been refreshed, the content returns to the initial value instead of showing the updated value.

I tried to use a configuration option as described [Here](http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/#options):

```
function follow(f1,f2) {
    $.get('/exe/add_followers.php?f1=' + f1 + '&f2=' + f2, function (result) {
        // $('.div'+f2).html('content 1 is updated to' + result.newcontent);
        $('.settings').tooltipster('update', 'content 1 is updated to' + result.newcontent);
        }, 'json');
}
```

However, this change the div1's content but removes the content of other divs. How can I update only the content of div1 and leave the other unchanged?

**==EDIT==**

I prefer a solution that do not pass the all set of divs, like follow:

```
function follow(f1,f2) {
    $.get('/exe/add_followers.php?f1=' + f1 + '&f2=' + f2, function (result) {
        $('.settings').tooltipster('update', '
                                              <div class='div1' onclick='follow(1,2)'>'+result.newcontent+'</div>
                                              <div class='div2' ...>Content 2</div>
                                              <div class='div3' ...>Content 3</div>
                                             ');
        }, 'json');
}
```

Comment: Its the problem with quotations given on title attribute.

Comment: @ram Could you elaborate? Please!

Comment: Try to escape title attribute values with combination of ' and " to escape html as string

Comment: It does works. The html becomes a mess. Moreover, [here](http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/#getting-started), in the "Using HTML tags inside your tooltips" section, says to "use single quotes when setting attributes".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I realized that rendering a large amount of html from title attribute is a bad approach! So, I  found that tooltipster is not suitable for my needs and I started to use [jQuery Bootstrap-style Dropdowns](http://glurl.co/c2U).

Comment: Why do you think it's a bad approach?

Answer (score 9):

I found this command work to change title:

```
$('#selectorElement').tooltipster('content', 'new title');
```

Comment: Are you sure that it works? cause I get "Tooltipster: one or more tooltips are already attached to the element below. Ignoring."